# How can I have timing default to on with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the psql client on a linux machine, and I always want timing to be on.
Is there a config file or setting somewhere to do this?
I am currently always starting my session with: `\timing`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a file called ~/.psqlrc and add the line:

```
\timing
```

Read the psql man page for more details.